# swap two adjacent edge pieces of a white face

Tags: rubiks-cube

Could anyone show me how to swap two adjacent edge pieces of a white face so that the U face is fully aligned? the configuration (real) is as follows: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not complete. For example, are all the greyed out faces already solved?

Now, when solving a Rubick's cube by the beginners solution, you're supposed to form a cross on your `U` layer/face with all the edges atop their respective centre squares. That would prevent you from having a configuration like this.

One quick fix might be `R'U'RUR'` and then you'll have to fix your corners on `U`.

But if I were you, I'd turn `U` 45deg and pop the centre edges and swap them!

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlexL, great to hear! Cheers!